# Listview Click Event (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, listview, firemonkey

[image]

It might be a simple question but i don't know; how to add listview item click event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `fmx.TListView` there is an event, [FMX.ListView.TCustomListView.OnItemClick](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.ListView.TCustomListView.OnItemClick).

Just define an event handler for this event.

The Event prototype is declared as:

```
TItemEvent = procedure(const Sender: TObject; const AItem: TListViewItem) of object;
```

Comment: how can i add double click item?

Comment: See [FMX.Controls.TControl.OnDblClick](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.OnDblClick). You will have to look up the selected item by code.

Comment: Go into the Object Inspector, click the Events tab, and double-click on the event that you want to handle, eg., OnClick, OnDblClick, etc. That will create an empty method that you can put your code into. It also adds a line to the form definition for the method it just created.